# Why does Data.append(Mutable​Range​Replaceable​Random​Access​Slice<Data>) append slice.count bytes from the beginning of the base collection?

Tags: swift, foundation

Using [Data.append(Mutable​Range​Replaceable​Random​Access​Slice)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/data/2832819-append), I expected the bytes within the start/end indexes of the provided slice to be appended onto the Data instance. Instead, it appears `Slice.count` bytes from the beginning of the `Slice.base` underlying collection are appended. In contrast, instantiating Data with a slice results in the bytes between the slice's start and end indexes populating the instance.

```
// Swift Playground, Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162)
import Foundation
var fooData = Data()
let barData = Data([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
let slice = barData.suffix(from: 3)
fooData.append(slice) // [0, 1, 2]
Data(slice) // [3, 4, 5]
```

Is this the expected behavior and, if so, what might help me better understand the behavior of `Data.append` in this context, and its differences from `Data.init`?

Additionally, given that the docs for [Mutable​Range​Replaceable​Random​Access​Slice](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mutablerangereplaceablerandomaccessslice) encourage using slices "only for transient computation", do  `Data.init` and `Data.append` reference the `Slice.base` collection or create their own copy of the bytes?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, but with `fooData.append(contentsOf: slice)` you get the expected result.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a bug. Looking at [the implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/Data.swift#L1288) for core-libs foundation, they're just accessing the `base` and appending the same number of bytes as the slice's count, without first offsetting the pointer. Doesn't help that there's no (as far as I can see) documentation on the method.

Answer (score 1):

I've filed a JIRA issue, which is likely the best place to continue tracking a possible answer:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4473